# C++ Does converting long, short and all ints to uint32_t, int32_t and so forth help at all?

Tags: c++, function, int

I run a gaming server that is coded C++, also a bit of ASM and C there. I saw someone had updated the same server I run and amongst all the updates was the fact that all int, unsigned, short and everything else he had changed to int32_t, uint32_t, uint64_t and the rest.

Is there any benefit in changing all of them to the above said ones? Lets say I changed all int to int32_t and all unsigned int to uint32_t and of course everything else thats possible to change.

I was trying to read and understand if there are any benefits but I simply didnt grasp the real meaning of them. So yeah, the question goes: Is there any benefit in doing what I just said?

The compiler I use is Orwell Dev-C++

Comment: `int32_t` has a specified size and range. `int` and `long` are vague. Only minimums are specified and their size is implementation specific.

Comment: Do you know the used compiler options and system architecture?

Comment: The types `int32_t`, `uint32_t` etc. are all of a fixed size and signedness. The native type `int` can be other sizes than 32 bits. This is important when coding for multiple platforms, as not all of them have types of the same size. For example `long`, which in some compilers are 64 bits on *some* 64-bit platforms, but other compilers have it as 32 bits even on 64-bit platforms. The signedness isn't so much of a problem besides for `char`.

Comment: It's good for portability and general robustness, but probably doesn't make much difference if you're only ever building and targetting one particular configuration where the code already works.

Comment: The server is ran on a Windows 7 64 bit system. So making it suitable for multiple platforms isnt important. I just hope in some way to improve performance of the game and the network and so forth.

Comment: It's unlikely to make any performance difference since you're presumably just using a different name for the same sized type.  It does make a big difference when you have code that compiles on Windows and Linux where `long` isn't the same size and you're reading/writing them to binary data.

Comment: Ask the person who made the change why they did it

Comment: Making that change guarantees that your code won't compile on a platform that doesn't have integral types that are **exactly** 32 bits wide. Since you haven't mentioned a requirement for those **exact** sizes, at least use `int_least32_t` and `uint_least32_t`, which will exist on all platforms.

Comment: If you ask the person who changed all the ints to int32_t, they will probably say "for portability". Then you should ask them how it specifically improves portability, and how much experience they have coding on machines where int is *not* 32 bits.  Most of the 'int' in C code should be 'int', even if int happens to be 16 bits on the machine. They may also say something like, "it was coding policy where I used to work ... I'm pretty sure it was for portability or something".

Answer (score 3):

The normal types, like `int` and `unsigned int`, have variable size depending on which platform you run. `int32_t` and `uint32_t`, however, is guaranteed to be 32 bits on any platform which have a 32-bit integral type. On platforms that don't, it doesn't exist. The size of a `int` may vary, usually its 32 or 64 bits long. The same rules apply to the other types, like `int64_t` is 64 bits.

To know the size of the data types is needed for instance in network programming because the network packets are sent between different platforms with different default integral sizes while the size of the data stored in the packets, like addresses and port numbers, are always the same. An IPv4-address is always 32 bits long, and one should use a data type which is guaranteed to be this size to store it.

In most programs, where you just store numbers, you should use the normal types. The size of these is the most efficient on the current platform.

Comment: Could updating them perform the games networking then? For instance the connection between server-client, if only those things are updated on the server.

Comment: No, but they have probably done it to make it work on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms. Maybe some of their code depend on the size of the integers. Also, they might have done it to save memory on 64-bit platforms, as you can, if done correctly, reduce memory usage for integers by 50% if you use 32-bit insted of 64-bit.

Comment: `int32_t` is guaranteed to be 32 bits **on platforms that have a 32-bit integral type**. On platforms that don't, it **doesn't exist**.

Comment: @Pete, I can add that, which platforms haven't got it?

Comment: @Atle - the platform that you have to port your code to under a tight deadline, of course. `<g>`.

Comment: @Atle: This isn't a perfect example, but the Texas Instruments C6000 compiler includes a `int40_t`. You won't find that on your typical gcc compiling for intel.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Can you support that with a quote from C++ standard?

Comment: Int32_t is guaranteed to be 32-bits, not necessarily 4 bytes.

Comment: @SigTerm - "The header defines all functions, types, and macros the same as 7.18 in the C standard." [cstdint.syn]/2. And from the C standard: "These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, it shall define the corresponding typedef names." 7.18.1.1/3. It's not quite as strong as I had remembered. Nevertheless, if you need at least 32 bits, `int_least32_t` is much better choice than `int32_t`.

Comment: @bames53, I replaced all references to bytes with bits.

Comment: @PeteBecker: "These types are optional" I see. I have no other questions.

Answer (score 2):

`uint32_t` and `int32_t` add a little bit more control to the handling of your data types by having a fixed size and sign - IMHO the more predictability you have in your program, the better it is. You also can see on the typename whether it is unsigned or not which may not always be self-evident

With well defined size you also are more protected when doing portable code.

Comment: No, there are no additional restrictions on conversions. `uint32_t` and `int32_t` are `typedef`s for a corresponding builtin integer type. The constraint that they do impose is that the **do not exist** if the target platform does not have an integral type with those **exact** sizes.

Comment: yes you are of course right, i've edited my answer, thanks for the headsup.

Comment: [u]int32_t, [u]int16_t, [u]int8_t will have a common size across different processors (where possible). But it's not a magic bullet:  E.g. in ` int16_t x = -1; uint16_t thresh  = 3;   ... if( x>thresh ) ` ,  `x>thresh`  will be true on a 16-bit machine (hopefully with a compiler warning) and false where int is 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the default int and long are so vague and compiler/platform dependent that I for one try to avoid them. With int and long:

- If you need to know the size of your struct, you need to know how many bytes for int and long, per architecture, per operative system, per compiler. It's a  waste of precious brain.
- If you need to explain to somebody the probability of having a collision in that hash table, would you say "it depends on the size of int, which depends on your architecture", or would you rather say, 1.0e-5? In other words, int and long "undefine" the properties of your program.
- If you use int, and the compiler swears that that's 64 bits, the chances of it optimizing it to 32 or 16 are minimal. So you end up using much more memory if all you wanted was space for representing a short symbol... not that I know of many alphabets with 2^32 characters.

With more informative types, like uint32_t, or uint_least32_t, your compiler can perhaps make better assumptions and use 64 bits if it believes that that would bring better performance. I don't know that for sure. But you as human have better chances of understanding the range of values in which your program works well.

Additionally, all binary protocols likely need to specify the size and endianess of integers.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with `int32_t` in some contexts, such as struct fields, but the
practice of writing all your `int` as `int32_t`, and `unsigned` as `uint32_t` (for portability?) is much overused; I think, in practical terms, you don't get any real portability benefit from this, and there are some significant downsides.

- Most likely the code you are writing will only ever be compiled on a machine where `int` is 32 bits. If you are going to port it to a machine with 16-bit ints, then you generally have much bigger problems than a blanket typedef will solve.
- If you do move to a 16-bit machine, you are probably going to want to change a great number of the local `int32_t` variables to `int` anyway since most of them are counts and indices, the 16-bit machine can't have more than 32K of most things, but people just wrote them all that way out of habit, and if you leave them as `int32_t` the code will be huge and slow.
- `int` being 64 bits in the future sometime? Won't happen, for a number of reasons, most of them just pragmatic things.
- On some weird machines `int` could be e.g. 24 bits. Very unusual, but again, you have bigger problems than a typedef will solve, and likely the first thing you want to do if porting to such a beast, is to change all the `int32_t` which are just counting things back to `int`.

So much for it not solving portability problems. What downside is there?

- Certain library functions have `int *` parameters, e.g. frexp. You need to supply an address of an int variable, or it won't port, and int32_t may or may not be int even if int is 32 bits (see below). I've seen people write `frexp( val, (int*)&myvar);` just so they can write  `int32_t myvar;` instead of `int myvar;`, which is terrible and can create a bug undetected by the compiler if int32_t is ever a different size from int.
- Likewise `printf( "%d", intvar);`  requires an int, not some typedef which happens to be the same size as int but might really be long, and gcc/clang issue warnings about this if int32_t is `long`.
- On many platforms `int32_t` is long (32-bit long), even though `int` is also 32 bits, this is unfortunate (and I think it can be traced back to Microsoft needing to thunk things over 16/32/64 and deciding that long should be 32 bits forever and vice versa).
- The uncertainty of whether int32_t is int or long can cause issues with c++ overloads, when porting code across different platforms.